# Установка FFMpeg на OpenServer

Tags: php, composer, ffmpeg

Всем привет!

Никак не могу понять как установить вот этот модуль https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg для OpenServer. В гугле не нашёл инструкций. На странице модуля написано, что его нужно устанавливать через https://getcomposer.org/. Установил Composer, скачал FFMpeg. По пути установки Composer появилась папка vendor\php-ffmpeg. Но как её теперь связать с OpenServer? В инструкции, в php файле добавляется строкой: require 'vendor/autoload.php';. Composer можно просто закинуть в папку с файлами сайта Openserver\domains\site.name?

Comment: Помойму это обычная PHP-библиотека. Как ей пользоваться в PHP на странице в github написано.

Comment: Для начала вам нужно настроить локальный домен в OpenServer, а уже после этого в папке домена развернуть свой проект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Установил Composer

Не нужно, он уже встроен в OpenServer.

> По пути установки Composer появилась папка vendor\php-ffmpeg. Но как её теперь связать с OpenServer?

Похоже, Вы установили библиотеку в служебную папку композера. Удалите её оттуда, если я не ошибаюсь. Затем повторите установку пакета, но уже следуя ниже приведенной инструкции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Запустите OpenServer
2. Откройте консоль из вкладки "Дополнительно"
3. Перейдите из C:\OSPanel в папку вашего приложения командой `cd domains\MyApp`
4. Установите библиотеку командой `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`

Готово, теперь вы можете использовать FFMpeg в php-файлах своего проекта.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
// Выполняем какие-то действия...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.